# Traceur JS - window is not defined

Tags: javascript, traceur

I have an existing project that accesses some variables off of the window scope. changing them around is an option, but I'd like to understand why the following isn't working...

```
//test.js
window.alert('I work');
```

```
traceur test.js
// -> ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?
I cannot import window nor could I find any reference to how to fix this through searching.

Comment: are you running this on a browser?

Comment: @Bhavin I'm running it in the command line.  traceur was installed via npm - version 0.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, you need to specify and output file if you want to compile your files to target the browser.

this command worked for me

```
traceur --out compiled.js test.js
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it in command line you then there is no window object. window object are specific to browser.
The window object represents an open window in a browser.
I am not sure what traceur is and if it was build based on the intention to run on anywhere else except a browser window.

If not, then all references to things like window or dom (Document Object Model) will fail..

Comment: Obviously the command line has no access to the dom. That being said, this is a transpiler.. the error I'm getting makes no sense as part of build step. it wouldn't make sense for ugilify or coffeescript to yell about a missing dom object either.